# How to define and marshall BSTR* types

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, com-interop, unmarshalling

i was wondering how to marshall string types to BSTR* types.
just to elaborate, the C++ structure is as follows:

```
struct MyStruct
{
     BSTR* string;
     int a;
}
```

i need to define a new sturct in C# side, i tried both string[] and IntPtr[] but that didn't come up with a success.

Thanks for your help!

edit:
c++ structure:

```
    struct HTTPTEXTRENDERERFILTERINFO {
        enum { UTC, GMT } eTimestamp;
        BOOL    bEnableCCIngest;
        LONG    lQueueSizeTreshold; 
        LONG    lSendTimeTreshold;  
        BYTE    btBroadcastUrlCount;
        BSTR*   pbstrBroadcastUrls;                                
        LONG    lInputPinsNum;      
    };
```

and the function's prototype:

```
HRESULT HTTPTextRendererFilter::SetConfig(IN const HTTPTEXTRENDERERFILTERINFO& Config)
```

c# structure:

> [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
>       public struct HttpTextRenderFilterInfo
>       {
>           public enum TimestampType : int { UTC, GMT };
>
> ```
>     public TimestampType Timestamp;
>     public int EnableCCIngest;
>     public int QueueSizeTreshold; 
>     public int SendTimeTreshold;  
>     public byte BroadcastUrlCount;
>     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
>     public string pbstrBroadcastUrls;        
>     public int lInputPinsNum;     
> };
> ```

prototype:

```
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetConfig([In] ref HttpTextRenderFilterInfo config);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
struct MyStruct
{
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] public String myString;
   public int a;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there anything different i should do, while assigning a new value to the string? Marshal.stringToPtr and so on..?

Comment: the entire structure forwarded from the c# to the c++ side is corrupted, no meaningful values, i will edit my original post to show the case